# has no exported member 'Firebase'

Tags: firebase, ionic2

I am trying to add Firebase in my ionic2 project from: https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/firebase/

After installing, I got this error:

> /myApp2/node_modules/ionic-native/dist/es5/index"' has no exported member 'Firebase'.

```
       L9:  import { Firebase } from 'ionic-native';
```

Anyone has solution for this?

Comment: Any update about this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use `import * as Firebase from 'firebase';` instead.

Comment: I am still getting errors when trying to use functions from this page( https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/firebase). I need Firebase only for Analytics and Push notifications.

Comment: Work fine for me in angular.

Answer (score 0):

ionic-native does not have firebase in it. 
firebase should be available globally once you install the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was following instructions from Ionic native plugin docs (https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/firebase/). I wanted to use this plugin for analytics and push notifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's firebase versioning problem . If you use 4.5.0 version try to downgrade your version , I downgraded from firebase 4.5.0 to 4.3.0 . so resolved.